# Как из одного роутера перейти в другой роутер(aiogram)?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

*/App/handlers.py*

```py
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message

from app.KeyBoard.button import create_inlineKeyBoard

router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer("Добро пожаловать!"
                     "Выберите меню:", reply_markup=create_inlineKeyBoard())
```

*/App/admin.py*

```py
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message

from app.KeyBoard.button import create_inlineKeyBoard

router = Router()

@router.callback_query()
async def admin_panel(cb: CallbackQuery):
    if cb.from_user.id == id_admin:
```

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте добавьте их в свой dispatcher aiogram сам разберется в какой handler передать сообщение добавить его можно вот так: `dp.include_routers(router,router)`